# Flesch-Kincaid and Linguistics

Tags: forensic-linguistics

I'm trying to place the Flesch-Kincaid grade level test in terms of a linguistic sub-field. Any ideas of what that sub-field would be?

I'm thinking it might be forensic linguistics but I am very unsure here and would appreciate help with determining its sub-field.

All the best!

Comment: Actually is must be stylistics?

Comment: It is not linguistics of any kind. It deals with printed official educational materials in English only, and it uses the number of letters in words as the primary datum. This has nothing to do with anything linguistic, and linguists are not responsible for it. It is the product of educationists.

Answer (score 1):

**Applied linguistics.**

The method draws on computational/quantitative linguistics and writing systems. (It could – and, one might argue, should – draw on psych/cognitive/neurolinguistics too, but I don’t think it does; see the [Coh-Metrix index](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/j.1545-7249.2008.tb00142.x) for an alternative based on psy-ling).

But whatever methods it draws on, the grading formula isn’t a theory; it’s a practical, educational tool.  This puts it in the domain of applied linguistics.  Graded readers in general are a well-established topic within applied linguistics (see e.g. Nation & Ming-tzu, *Graded Readers and Vocabulary*, or Krashen’s body of work on the comprehension hypothesis.)